# Get environment name in AWS Lambda function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, development-environment

I want to get the environment name (dev/qa/prod) where my AWS Lambda function is running or being executed programatically. I don't want to give as part of my environment variables.
How do we do that?

Comment: As per your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64324643/get-environment-name-in-aws-lambda-python) on the same topic, **what do you mean by "environment name"?** This is something that _you_ would define, so AWS has no knowledge of it. Is each environment running in a **different AWS Account**? If so, the Lambda function could look at the account number and use that to determine an 'environment'. Basically, the concept of "dev/qa/prod" is totally _your_ construct, and is not something that AWS understands natively. Thus, _your code_ needs to determine the environment.

Comment: Each Environment in AWS has different role.

Answer (score 2):

In AWS, everything is in "Production". That is, there is no concept of "AWS for Dev" or "AWS for QA".

It is up to *you* to create resources that you declare to be Dev, QA or Production. Some people do this in different AWS Accounts, or at least use different VPCs for each environment.

Fortunately, you mention that *"each environment in AWS has a different role"*.

This means that the AWS Lambda function can call [`get_caller_identity()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_caller_identity) to obtain "details about the IAM user or role whose credentials are used to call the operation":

```py
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
    print(sts_client.get_caller_identity())
```

It returns:

```json
{
    "UserId": "AROAJK7HIAAAAAJYPQN7E:My-Function",
    "Account": "111111111111",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts: : 111111111111:assumed-role/my-role/My-Function",
    ...
    }
}
```

Thus, you could **extract the name of the Role being used** from the `Arn`.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda function can do one of the following :

1. `def handler_name(event, context):` - read the data from the `event` dict. The caller will have to add this argument (since I dont know what is the lambda trigger I cant tell if it is a good solution)
2. Read the data from S3 (or other storage like DB)
3. Read the data from AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store

> I don't want to give as part of my environment variables

Why?

Comment: as per my requirement, I should not be giving as part of environment variables or input. If we are giving env as event dict then it will be input I should not be doing that